# Edge detection in spatial or in frequency domain?

Tags: image-processing, filter, image-segmentation, edge-detection

I want to ask why everywhere is used to do edge detection in spatial domain and not in frequency domain with FFT of image and apply HP filter. Thank you.

Comment: Not sure why this would be a good idea, spatial information is crucial for edge detection. You could say it's almost the only thing that really matters, why would you ever do this anywhere other than spatial domain?

Comment: Lookup "edge detection Fourier transform".